Save a customized order in Notion
I'm not sure how many people on here know of Notion, but basically it's a customizable app/website that let's you make whatever you want from grocery lists, to-do list, homework schedules, recipe books, etc. I have found I like it best for recipes.
So I have a Recipe Book on there and I want to make the order a specific way. I've dragged and dropped them into a particular order and I want them to stay like that as a savable preset.
I know I can add another property and number them like that but I'd like to avoid having too many unneccesary properties if I can. I've tried Googling it and I haven't found anything that corresponds with this. I just see that I can have it like this, but I don't see a way to save it where I can alternate through different views based on what I'm looking for.
